# Add header to multi server or instance query (powershell)

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have the following PowerShell script I am looking to add a header to this results without having a duplicate per each iteration but I am not familiar enough with Powershell if anyone can point me in the right direction it would be helpful.

> $servers = 'E:\DBA\servers.txt' 
>   $outfile = 'E:\DBA\out.csv' 
>   $queryfile = 'E:\DBA\query.sql'
>
> Get-Content $servers -First 1 | ForEach-Object {Invoke-SqlCmd -inputfile $queryfile -ServerInstance $_ -Database master | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -First 1 | Out-File
>   $outFile -Force} Get-Content $servers | ForEach-Object {Invoke-SqlCmd -inputfile $queryfile -ServerInstance $_ -Database master | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File -Append $outFile}

The error is 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to hard-code the header, you can use the [Powershell New-Item cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item).  I used the -Force parameter to initialize the outfile with the single header row and the rest of your script uses -Append to add the detail information.

```
New-Item $outfile -value "Header,Header,Header,Header`n" -Force
Get-Content $servers | ForEach-Object {Invoke-SqlCmd -inputfile $queryfile -ServerInstance $_ -Database master | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File -Append $outFile}
```

If you want dynamic columns generated based on the actual query, you can run an initial Get-Content using -First 1 (to only get the first server) and limit the output to the first row only by using -First 1.  Then, follow up with your usual Powershell script.

```
Get-Content $servers -First 1 | ForEach-Object {Invoke-SqlCmd -inputfile $queryfile -ServerInstance $_ -Database master | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -First 1 | Out-File $outFile -Force}
Get-Content $servers | ForEach-Object {Invoke-SqlCmd -inputfile $queryfile -ServerInstance $_ -Database master | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File -Append $outFile}
```

Comment: That can work on long term runs but for a bit more dynamic no still, that helps in some scenarios.

Comment: @Enrique - Just letting you know that I updated my answer, which should allow you to retrieve the header information from the actual query instead of hard-coding the header information.

Comment: Thanks, Scott I was going to work today on this, I will be sure to check both of your answer and thanks.

Comment: Thanks Scoth it work but I am getting a weird error even when it works correctly and I am not that good to see the error.

<code>At D:\DBAPoSH\Mail\QueryExecuteMultiServer.ps1:11 char:49
+ Get-Content $servers -First 1 | ForEach-Object {Invoke-SqlCmd -inputfile $queryf ...
+                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], PipelineStoppedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlExectionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand</code>

Comment: Strange - I didn't receive any errors during my tests - can you update your  post to include your entire Powershell script?  Perhaps you have something extra.  You might also try to update the file that $servers points to and include only ONE server to facilitate testing.

Comment: Hello Scott sorry the delay, I have reduced the code and still get this error on this little one. It does work but I don't see a reason why it is throwing the error

Comment: It looks like you're getting some kind of Sql exception.  Have you tried altering the file that contains the list of servers to only have ONE server that you know works?  Perhaps there is some data (or unknown characters) in the file pointed to by $Servers that is causing the problem.  Altering your $Server file to only contain one entry may help you isolate the problem.  If one server name works, continue to add until you get the error.

Comment: I have tried that. And still no issue but I will check again later today. Still I am wondering why the error even if isn't causing an issue... its more like I just want to know why

Comment: I am afraid even with a very simple query, removing go and adding ; at the end it doesn't work I am really unsure on whats wrong (or why its working no less).

Test it with a single server.

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose when I don't have your servers to test against.  My recommendation is to add some error handling logic to your Powershell script using the examples here - http://sqlmag.com/powershell/handling-errors-powershell